# How to hide cell in table view controller for edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have to manage two things on single **table view controller**.I have a profile screen in which there is a field of password which remains hidden when a user is logged in but when user clicks on **edit button** then he can see password field also and can edit his password.
I m unable to hide the particular cell and its height while login.How can I manage that???

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the data for the row(s) you are removing. In your case you could probably just switch to a different dataset since you're not working with dynamic data.
2. Determine what index path(s) you need to delete (very likely corresponds to the index in an array that was holding your table data.
3. Call `[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

If you <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd> on `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` you'll see there are lots of animation options.

To get it back, just do the opposite. Add data and call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`